# Conditional probabilities of correlated normal distributed random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, correlation

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be standard normal distributed random variables with Covariances
$$\mathrm{Cov}(X_i, X_j)=g_{i,j}=g_{j,i}>0.$$
How can one proof that
$$P(X_n < a | X_1, ..., X_{n-1}< a) \geq P(X_n < a | X_1, ..., X_{i}< a) \qquad \forall i< n-1$$
holds true?

Thanks!

Edit: We assume that $a>0$ and that the vector $(X_1,..., X_n)$ ist multivariate gaussian.

Comment: Do you assume that the vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is Gaussian? Otherwise, the assumptions are very weak. Is $a$ a positive real number, any real number?

Comment: Thx ! I was sloppy on that part and added these two assumptions in an Edit!

Comment: Some similarity with submartingale definition...

Comment: Do you think this can be used for a proof? Mhh.